# Yii url route with parameters

Tags: url, yii, url-mapping

At the moment i have a glossar controller with an actionAnzeige()-method.

For this action i need GET-paramter named item.

Now i could use this url: **www.xy.de/glossar/anzeigen?item=programming**

But i want to use this: **www.xy.de/glossar/programming**

I've added this route to the rules:

```
'glossar/<item:\d+>'=>'glossar/anzeigen',
```

and now i can generate the url i want to use:

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('glossar/anzeigen', array('item' => $glossarItem->Url)); ?>
```

But if i visit the created url, i get a 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `w+` instead of `d+` since `item` takes letters instead of digits

```
'glossar/<item:\w+>'=>'glossar/anzeigen',
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this, which accepts characters or numbers:

```
'glossar/<item:.+>'=>'glossar/anzeigen',
```